# I'm trying to find a value from an array with the index being a counter from a struct

Tags: c, arrays, struct

The question title might be a little confusing but I didn't want it to get too long. So here is the problem:

I have a structure with a counter.

```
typedef struct location{
    int count;
    char *name;
    arc *arcs[10];
}location;
```

I am trying to increment this counter, using it as the index of an array.

```
current->locptr->arcs[current->locptr->count] = malloc(sizeof(arc));
current->locptr->count++;
```

current is a node of a linked list structure, locptr is a location structure, and arcs[] is an array of arc structures.

Is this possible? My code crashes every time at the malloc line.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: The other structs

```
/*
 * Arc lengths to and from locations. Has a name, and a number.
 */
typedef struct arc{
    int cost;
    char *to;
    char *from;
}arc;

/*
 * Location struct that can point to up to 10 other locations.
 * This struct also contains the name of the establishment.
 */
typedef struct location{
    int count;
    char *name;
    arc *arcs[10];
}location;

/*
 * Linked list that contains a pointer to the location struct.
 */
typedef struct node{
    struct node *next;
    location *locptr;
}node;
```

Comment: Would be good if you post `linked list structure` here

Comment: Added the other structs!

Comment: crashes.... how? What error? Have you tried compiling with debug symbols and running it in a debugger to see exactly what's happening?

Comment: Its give me no error, the program just stops working. Sorry, I'm not quite sure how to use a debugger, or debug symbols.

Comment: @Nickname97 : Is memory allocated for `char *to` & `char *from`?

Comment: You said the crash is at the malloc line. Try add the check in my post and try again.

Comment: @sjsam Shouldn't the malloc take care of that?

Comment: malloc takes takes care of the pointer you're dealing with. What if the pointer has an object which is still a pointer?

Comment: Sorry @sjsam, I'm a bit confused. Could you explain a bit more what you mean?

Comment: @Nickname97 :  I have put an answer. But it is really not a good idea having multiple indirections without the help of a debugger and some error checking as \@fluter mentioned.

Comment: You have a bug somewhere in your program. To get help post a  [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2):

```
malloc(sizeof(arc));
```

may be problematic. After you do :

```
arcs[i]=malloc(sizeof(arc));
```

You are probably not allocating memory for `to` and `from` ie :

```
arcs[i]->to=malloc(length_you_want*sizeof(char))
arcs[i]->from=malloc(length_you_want*sizeof(char))
```

Any pointers in your structures cannot be used without dynamically allocating memory for them. So you need to check `char *name;` in your `location` as well.

**Note :**  sizeof(char) is almost always one, so you can omit it or you could put try `malloc(length * sizeof *ptr)` style which is considered portable.

Answer (score 1):

At least, you should use defensive programming when dealing with multiple levels of indirections:

```
// current->locptr->arcs[current->locptr->count] = malloc(sizeof(arc));
struct node *current = ...;

if (current && current->locptr) {
    if (current->locptr->count >= sizeof(current->locptr->arcs)/sizeof(current->locptr->arcs[0]) {
        // error, arcs can have only 10 elements
    }
    current->locptr->arcs[current->locptr->count]  = malloc(sizeof(arc));
    current->locptr->count++;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. This wasn't the problem though. I still get the same crash.

Comment: Which line does it crash? Please post the message and the surrounding code.

Answer (score 1):

There are several approaches you can take, but when you are dealing with any complex node data structure requiring allocation in a linked list, you should take it piece-by-piece. Generally that means creating a separate `T *createT (...);` function that can fully allocate each type `T` for use within your list structure setup.

At minimum you would need a `location *createloc (...)` and a `node *createnode (...)`. The `createnode` function is called by your `insertnode` function that inserts the node in the list. Your `createloc` funciton is called by `createnode`. (you are of course free to fill in the individual data whenever that makes sense to do)

You should also write a `void deleteT` function that properly frees each type of struct used within your list data structure setup. The remainder of your list operations should be fairly generic.

In your case, you can do something similar to the following for your `location` struct. (you will create/allocate/fill each `arc` later, for now initialize to `NULL`):

```
location *createloc (int cnt, char *nm, const char *to, 
                     const char *from)
{
    size_t i;
    location *loc = NULL;   /* create location struct */

    if (!(loc = malloc (sizeof *loc))) {   /* allocate/validate */
        fprintf (stderr, "createloc() error: memory exhausted.\n");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    loc->count = cnt;   /* initialize or set default */
    loc->name = nm ? strdup (nm) : NULL;
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) (loc->arcs)[i] = NULL;

    return loc;
}
```

(*note:* instead of looping to initialize each poiner in `loc->arcs`, you can make a single call to `memset` (e.g. `memset (loc->arcs, 0, 10 * sizeof *(loc->arcs));`)

`createloc` is then called from your `createnode` function:

```
node *createnode (int cnt, const char *nm, const char *to,
                  const char *from)
{
    node *tmp = NULL;   /* create node */

    if (!(tmp = malloc (1, sizeof *tmp))) { /* allocate/validate */
        fprintf (stderr, "createnode() error: memory exhausted.\n");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /* create/allocate location */
    tmp->locptr = createloc (cnt, nm, to, from);

    return node;
}
```

You will populate each `arc` pointer within the `location` struct with something simalar to the following as that data becomes available, either through a read from a file or otherwise:

```
arc *createarc (int cost, const char *to, const char *from)
{
    arc *tmp = NULL;

    if (!(tmp = malloc (1, sizeof *tmp))) {
        fprintf (stderr, "createarc() error: memory exhausted.\n");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    tmp->cost = cost;
    tmp->to = to ? strdup (to) : NULL;
    tmp->from = from ? strdup (from) : NULL;

    return tmp;
}
```

Using it in some fashion in a loop where you are allocating for each `node->locptr->arcs` pointer:

```
arc *ap = node->locptr->arcs;  /* a pointer to the arcs array */
...
ap[0] = createarc (50, "this place", "that place");
```

Taking an approach like this will insure, at minimum, you have all necessary pieces in your data structure makeup for your list allocated and validated when you create each node. **note:** since there is no MCVE, I have not tested each of these functions. That is left for you.